# UiTabBar with more than 5 tags

Tags: iphone, uitabbar, viewcontroller

I have a tabbar with more than 5 view controllers.

Iphone adds a 5th tab ,called 'MORE'.

But as much as i've researched, i can't find a way to rename it to the Spanish version, "MAS".

Anyone can help ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you provide a localised Spanish version of your app, it will display the Spanish text.

System provided UI and text in the iPhone will display in the default localisation of the app, which is probably English. If you localise your app for each region you wish to support, then the localised text and UI will be used for that region.

The system will know which region to use when the app launches depending on what the user's iPhone's locale is set to.

Comment: Great !! It was that .. i didn't realise i can add a "es" localization to the info.plist ..  Thanks a lot !